# How can I use either cloud or on-premise storage

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, abstraction, azure-storage-files

I have a C# application that can be deployed both on-premise or into the Azure cloud. The application is being deployed in a Linux container with the intent to be able to deploy this app to the cloud, or if a client requires it, to deploy it on premises. This means that I assume I have no control over the local file system.

I have been considering using SMB shares since both Windows and Linux support them, and I can set an application configuration setting that dictates the share location to be picked up at runtime.

The problem is that on-premise shares seem to be easy, but Azure Shares seem to be a bit harder. I know I can connect to them both, but I want to be able to abstract away the complexity of each from the business logic of the application.

So far, I'm not finding much that lets me abstract the file system in a way that I can use both on-premise and cloud/Azure file storage.